# How to use and if statement in linq Entity framework c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am declaring this variable to get data from my database(example)

```
var products = _context.Products();
```

and I need to use like this example

```
if(ctId == -1)
{
    // get project list 
    var products = _context.Products().where(a => a.categoryId == 2);
}
else
{
    //get category list
    var products = _context.Products().where(a => a.categoryId == 1);
}
```

but my problem how to declare `var products`
to using like this

```
if(ctId == -1)
{
    // get project list 
    products = _context.Products().where(a => a.categoryId == 2);
}
else
{
    //get category list
    products = _context.Products().where(a => a.categoryId == 1);
}
```

Comment: `IQueryable<Product> products`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the initial problem, you would declare an `IQueryable<Product>` outside the `if` scope

```
IQueryable<Product> products = null;

if(ctId == -1)
   products = _context.Products().where(a => a.categoryId == 2);
else
   products = _context.Products().where(a => a.categoryId == 1);
```

However, you could also use a [*ternary conditional operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

> The conditional operator `?:`, also known as the *ternary conditional
> operator*, evaluates a *Boolean expression* and returns the result of one
> of the two expressions, depending on whether the Boolean expression
> evaluates to `true` or `false`.
>
> The syntax for the conditional operator is as follows:
>
> ```
> condition ? consequent : alternative
> ```

**Example**

```
var id = ctId == -1 ? 2 : 1;
var products = _context.Products().where(a => a.categoryId == id);
```

or potentially

```
var products = _context.Products().where(a => a.categoryId == (ctId == -1 ? 2 : 1));
```

Comment: I would suggest you make it clear that you could add `IQueryable<Product> products` outside the `if`. I think you've kind of suggest that with the "There is nothing wrong with what you have" but I don't think the OP understands that - hence the question.